# jQuery change class of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html, parent

I have a simple question, I am new to this and I am not getting it. I am binding data to label id=lbl_ArrFlt. when that num is changed I want to change class of it's parent div. How do I do that?

```
 <li>
    <div class="top">
        <label>ARR FLT</label>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <label id="lbl_ArrFlt">{{ARRIVAL.FLT}}</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Right now I am trying this

```
$("#lbl_ArrFlt").parent().attr("class", "top noton");
```

What's wrong?

More Info --
There is a function which checks for new data. If new data

```
function highlightFor(){ 
    $("#lbl_ArrFlt").parent().attr("class", "top noton");
}
```

Comment: is your javascript wrapped in a $(document).ready(function()...

Comment: Your code should work, unless it is executed before DOM is loaded.

Comment: Your code seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VU8ZS/. How are you invoking it?

Comment: How do I check if DOM is loading first?

Comment: if you read your answers that people have made for you, you would know

Answer (score 1):

try this [jQuery addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) [jQuery ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function() {

   $("#lbl_ArrFlt").parent().addClass("top noton");

});
```

or the original

```
$(function() {
   $("#lbl_ArrFlt").parent().attr("class", "top noton");
});
```

The `$(function(){..});` in these code blocks is called when the `document` is ready
So then we can definitely be sure that `#lbl_ArrFlt` exists

Comment: If "top" is already there, just "noton" might make more sense.

Comment: Okay. I don't quite know how your CSS works, just making sure you know that means you will have two divs directly under your <li>: <div class="top"> and <div class="bottom top noton">

Comment: I Don't need to know really.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) on the elements to do this. In case you have to add and remove a class several times, [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) might be useful for you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his code. Maybe he wants to manually set the class attribute? Then your code will not work.

Comment: Beware of using `attr`, as there are some details to take into account. Documents [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: The document says there wouldn't be any problem setting `class` with `attr`; it even reminds you to use quotes around the "class"

Answer (score 0):

Use addClass() and removeClass() jquery method

```
$(document).ready() {

   $("#lbl_ArrFlt").parent().addClass("top noton");

});
```